# Sprite won't render at all?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

The classes look like this:

```
Game
has-a Player

Player
has-a SpriteInstance

SpriteInstance
has-a List<SpriteInstance>
```

Each render step, `Game` calls `Draw()` on `Player`. `Player` calls `draw()` on `SpriteInstance`. And `draw()` looks like this:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 offset = default(Vector2), float rotation = 0f)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, offset + pos, null, Color.White, rot+rotation, sprite.origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, z);
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        child.draw(spriteBatch, offset + pos, rotation + rot);
    }
}
```

My expected output is being able to see both the SpriteInstance on the screen, *and* each texture from each child of SpriteInstance, but my actual output is just the SpriteInstance and none of the children. I have tried using a debugger, but it shows that the child's draw() function is definitely called. And since `spriteBatch` is a magical black box that's as far as I can go...

Is there something wrong about passing spriteBatch around? Am I passing it by value somehow when it should be passed by reference?

**edit**: here are all the draw functions

Game

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();// sortMode: SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack);
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Player

```
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    }
```

**edit2**:

Bringing the spriteBatch.draw() calls out into the foreach loop does make it display, but I don't know what the difference is... it is also not a proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 offset = default(Vector2), float rotation = 0f)
{
spriteBatch.Begin(); //Starts the drawing loop

spriteBatch.Draw(texture, offset + pos, null, Color.White, rot+rotation,   sprite.origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, z);
foreach (var child in children)
{
    child.draw(spriteBatch, offset + pos, rotation + rot);
}
spriteBatch.End();  // This is for ending the drawing loop.
}
```

If that doesn't work I would like to see your main class, and a copy of the output you are getting when you run the application. Please also list any errors that  occur.

Comment: I already call Begin and End. There is no console output, because *something* shows up on the screen (the parent SpriteInstance) but not the children SpriteInstances. Posted the code tho.

Comment: Can you show where your loading the content? Also in the draw method what parameter are you sending the null to?

Comment: I figured it out, and it was a silly mistake--the z-buffer range is from 0 to 1 only, and I was trying to pass z=2 for the children.

Comment: And the few times it isn't it feels even worse! :P